# iOS 8 today extension - recompile

Tags: xcode, ios8, recompile

I create an extension for my app in iOS 8 and it is displayed correctly under the Today tab.

However when I make a change to the extension (either a UI change in the Storyboard, a UI change in `viewDidLoad` code, or some changes in the `widgetPerformUpdateWithCompletionHandler` method), there's nothing that is changed when I recompile. The only way I can make the changes to appear is to delete the app from the device/simulator then compile/install again. Restarting XCode (I work with XCode 6 beta 4) / restarting the computer does not help.

1. How can I fix the bug?
2. How am I supposed to debug the extension, because setting breakpoints does not seem to do anything and no NSLog messages are printed to the console (I suppose, since it's a different target).

Comment: The Release Notes for Betas is not just optional reading.

Answer (score 1):

1. It's a known bug, read the release notes for iOS 8b5.
2. Debugging (and NSLog) works in Xcode but not always (known bugs). You can still attach the debugger if Xcode cannot attach himself (Debug -> Attach to process)

For me, the simulator works better than real device, so use the simulator until things got better.

**2 tips:**

1. Close the simulator at end of debugging (i have a script for auto closing the simulator when i press STOP in Xcode, tell me if you want it).
2. When you launch the plugin process in simulator, wait for "All applications" display list, if you click "Run" before the list are loaded, the debugger won't attach.